# Php fwrite gives one line in each word

Tags: php, cakephp

This is my php code for fwrite function.
I want to output like oneworld than 2nd world on 2nd line and 3rd is on 3rd line

OUTPUT

```
05 10 2012 16:06:29  bonne 
05 10 2012 16:06:29   
05 10 2012 16:06:38  mauvais 
05 10 2012 16:06:38   
05 10 2012 16:06:44  pas bonne 
05 10 2012 16:06:45   
05 10 2012 16:07:17  trés bonne 
05 10 2012 16:07:18   
05 10 2012 16:07:34  bonne 
05 10 2012 16:07:35
```

there is one line between each word.
here is my code can you please help me

```
<?php
        $file = "testFile.txt";
        $fp = fopen($file, 'a');
        $name = $_POST['nom'];
        $mood = trim($_POST['Humer']);
        $date = date ("d m Y H:i:s");
        $data = $mood;
        fwrite($fp, "$date  $data \n");
        fclose($fp);
        ?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You write to file only one variable `$mood` with line break after it.
And about additional lines, try to trim data before:

```
$mood = trim($_POST['Humer']);
```

Comment: can you give me example..as i am new to php I dont know much syntax.. in my case what will be the right way to write

Comment: Simply change one line on line from my example.

Comment: not working same output.

Comment: How you view the result file?

Comment: <?php
$file = "testFile.txt";
$fp = fopen($file, 'a');
$name = $_POST['nom'];
$mood = trim($_POST['Humer']);
$date = date ("d m Y H:i:s");
$data = $mood;
fwrite($fp, "$date  $data \n");
fclose($fp);

?>